# Run/exclude specs where tag is present

Tags: ruby, rspec

I know I can run specs given `some_tag` is `value` with `--tag some_tag:value` or where tag is added, but doesn't have a value (defaults to `true`) with `--tag some_tag`. I also know I can exclude specs with the above syntax and `~`.

How do I run all specs with a tag present/missing?

For example:
If I have specs marked with `slow: :external_service`, `slow: :manual_confirmation` or `slow: :some_other_reason` (these are just made up names), I want to do something like:

```
rspec --tag ~slow
```

and run all specs that are not slow.

The above doesn't work since it filters out specs where `slow == true` instead of `!slow.nil?`

- Is there a way to achieve exactly this with or without extra configuration?
- What is the idiomatic way to do a such thing? I would guess add two tags, one boolean and one containing the value (for example `:slow, pending_on: :external_service`)

Comment: May be multiple tag exclude like `rspec --tag ~slow:external_service --tag ~slow:manual_confirmation` might help you here...

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, I added a comment under your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/tag-option#filter-examples-with-a-name:value-tag) should help. Basically call

```
rspec --tag ~slow:external_service
```

and it won't run tests tagged with `slow: :external_service`

Comment: OP actually wants to skip all those marked with slow key. Not just one

Answer (score 0):

Exclude with multiple tags can be of some help here.

`rspec --tag ~slow:external_service --tag ~slow:manual_confirmation`

Refer [this](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/tag-option#exclude-examples-with-multiple-tags) article for other options.

Comment: I know I can give multiple tag pairs. The point is - I don't want to have to list all possible slow values. For example - if a new slowdown reason is added in the future, I don't want to change the way I call rspec. Or if I have 100 reasons for slowdown I don't want the call to take the entire screen.

Comment: Then you should be go ahead with the second option that you proposed...add two tags, one boolean and one containing the value